# How to get specific line from output and save it in one variable?

Tags: bash, shell-script

When I run this command

```bash
user@ubuntu:~$ ./2input1output Jojo Ar Dublin
```

it gives me this output

```
Your First Name: Jojo 
Your Last Name : Ar 
Your Hometown : Dublin
Thank you, Jojo Ar From Dublin,
Welcome to Stackoverflow
```

Now I need to display the fourth and fifth lines from that output and then save it into a variable.  I have tried

```bash
user@ubuntu:~$ (sed -n 4,5p ./2input1output)
```

but it gave me this output

```
echo"Thank you, $1 $2 From $3,
Welcome to stackoverflow"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your command is actually working as expected; you are asking sed to return lines 4 and 5 from the file "2input1output". As you can see, the positional arguments (i.e. $1, $2 and $3) are returned because that is what is in the script.

What you need to do is actually run the script first in order to get the desired output (STDOUT) and then pipe that to the stream editor (sed). So, in one hit, to save the desired content to a variable:

```
$ MESSAGE=$(./2input1output Jojo Ar Dublin | sed -n 4,5p)
```

Please remember that if you need to preserve newline characters when accessing the variable, wrap it in double quotation marks first.

Comment: i think your answer is working, but how do i proof that `MESSAGE` contain line 4 and 5?

Comment: If you're setting the MESSAGE variable on the command line (as per my answer), you can run: echo $MESSAGE

Comment: i dont know how to do that, can you help me again?

Comment: In my answer, we used the variable MESSAGE to store the output of the script and the sed command. In order to see what MESSAGE contains, you can use the "echo" command. To do this, on the command line, type "echo $MESSAGE". Note the "$" sign in front of MESSAGE, this is important as it references the variable not the string.

Answer (score 0):

i think sed get fifth line from your script. you can send output to another file then sed lines you want from there or in your bash save output to a variable then grep the lines you want.

Answer (score 0):

We can do it by below method too using awk

```
MESSAGE=`sh 2input1output Jojo Ar Dublin| awk 'NR >3 && NR<=5 {print $0}'
```